# How to deploy a maven parent module with flat module hierarchy?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have 3 maven modules. One is the parent grouping the other 2 modules.
All project folders are on the same root level.

Though the deployment is not working. What's wrong with the following configuration?

```
project-parent/pom.xml
project-commons/pom.xml
project-web/pom.xml
```

parent-pom:

```
<project>
        <groupId>de.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <!-- <module>../project-commons</module> -->
        <module>../project-web</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

web-pom:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>de.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath>../project-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
```

Result:

```
[ERROR]   The project de.myproject:project-parent:1.0.0 has 1 error
[ERROR]     Child module \project-parent\..\project-web\pom.xml of \project-parent\pom.xml does not exist
```

The project structure:

```
svn/project-commons/trunk/pom.xml
svn/project-web/trunk/pom.xml
svn/project-parent/pom.xml
```

Comment: Can you show the directory structure of your project ?

Comment: delete the relative path of the parent pom....it will work. However I do not recommend the use of relative path...obviously you must first build the parent pom... The error, seeing yout project structure, depends by the fact that you parent pom is not in the relative path you declare...I see that all three project are at the same level, but you declare that the parent is in the previous path

Comment: I usually use this kind of structure and it works well. The one thing I do differently is that I have a pom at the top level. It is this top-level pom that knows which modules (rather than the parent, where you are getting your error) to build and has all the deployment specific stuff. This way, you can run maven from the command line (or Jenkins) in the top level directory. Not an answer to your question, but...

Comment: It seems you miss one level on your directory structure on your relative path. If you are building the child POM then the relative path (based on your structure) should be ../../project-parent/pom.xml see if it solve your problem

Comment: @Rob the reason I have the `project-parent` pom in a single project is that I want to introduce 2-3 more parent poms which aggregate some of the modules that are to come into a desired project, where each of these projects share only some of the submodules.

Comment: @membersound I think you may be confusing the concept (or at least terminology) of a parent pom (inherit settings, dependencies, properties, etc.) vs. the concept of building sets of modules and/or dependencies on sets of modules. A given module can have only one parent pom, but may be used by (and built as a dependency of) several modules/poms.

Comment: @JorgeCampos if I remove the svn-trunk structure the project builds fine with just one relative statement `../`. So somehow the rootcause is the trunk structure here...

Comment: @Rob oh ok, maybe I'm really confusing things. My goal is to have several poms that define the modules that the project needs, and then I only want to run `mvn package` on the parent so that all child modules get compiled and packaged automatically. What would such a "module" pom have to look like in contrast to a parent pom? And how do I actually invoke it?

Comment: So far I always thought a maven parent is also the module pom that is used to build the entire application.

Comment: I found out that if I change the module definition in the parent/aggregator to `<module>../project-web/trunk</module>` it works as expected. So is it really necessary to always include the trunk path in the module config?

Comment: @membersound That is what i said. if you change `<relativePath>../project-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>` to `<relativePath>../../project-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>` it should work

Comment: Yes ok great, that works at least! Though, my question: is it the right approach to add `/trunk/` to each of the modules in the aggregator? Or could this be done better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will outline an approach that I have used successfully on large and small projects that may meet your needs.

```
pom.xml
superpom/pom.xml
utils0/pom.xml
utils1/pom.xml
utils2/pom.xml
services0/pom.xml
services1/pom.xml
services2/pom.xml
war0/pom.xml
war1/pom.xml
```

In this example, the utils and services modules produce jars; the war modules produce wars. There would be various dependencies between the utils, services and wars.

The superpom modules is of type pom and just contains the parent pom. Each of the util/service/war pom.xml refer to the parent with the relative path of ../superpom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>superpom</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../superpom</relativePath>
</parent>
```

The superpom/pom.xml does NOT contain any  elements and does not refer to the "child" modules/poms in any way. The superpom contains shared properties, plugin configs, dependency versions, etc. It is a big pom. All the other module's poms are (generally) small.

The top-level pom contains the  references to all the other modules (including superpom). It does not have a parent pom (at least not one that lives within this project hierarchy). You use the top-level (not superpom) to build everything. You can use profiles (or other means) to control which modules you want to build, but I have generally just built the whole tree from here. Support for SCM, CI builds, etc. lives in this top-level pom, which keeps all your other projects (including the parent pom) clean and concerned only with building and testing the artifacts.

I don't have any concept of "trunk" in my maven structure - that is an orthogonal concept. If I want to work on trunk or a branch, I check out the appropriate one and always have the same maven structure.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. That really seems to fit my needs. One last question concerning the `trunk` structure: so you utils, services, war projects all are simple plain projects without any trunk-branch-tag structure. But you have a trunk structure around the whole configuration posted above. Eg trunk/pom.xml, trunk/superpom/pom.xml. And the same for branch and tags of course. Did I get that right?

Comment: And moreover: your modules' pom all define the parent in the following manner? `<relativePath>../superpom/pom.xml</relativePath>`?

Comment: @membersound Assuming you are using subversion... In your subversion repo you will have this structure defined under trunk and as you branch it will be replicated under branches/<branch-name> as well. When you (or any developer) wants to work on trunk or a branch, they will check out the appropriate path to whatever directory they want to work in - they may or may not name it using the branch name or trunk. Maven doesn't know or care about any of the subversion stuff (although some plugins might, such as the maven-release-plugin).

Comment: Edited the answer to address your relative path question.